# How to retrieve object

Tags: java

In the `Class2`, I want to retrieve the `objects(obj1,2)` method variables passed inside init class. But I am always getting `0` value in `Class2`. Please suggest how to get `obj1,2` variables in `Class2`. Thanks!

```java
public class Class1 {
    public int Value;

    public void setMethod(int val) {
        this.Value = val;
    }

    public int getMethod() {
        return Value;
    }
}

//initialization class
import Class1;

public class init {
    Class1 obj1 = new Class1();
    Class1 obj2 = new Class1();
    obj1.setMethod(10);
    obj2.setMethod(20);
    System.out.println("obj1 value is" + obj1.getMethod()); // it will print 10
    System.out.println("obj2 value is" + obj2.getMethod()); // it will print 20
}

//another class where I want my obj1, obj2 method variables to retrieve
import Class1;

private class Class2 {
    Class1 obj1 = new Class1();
    System.out.println("obj1 value is" + obj1.getMethod()); // it is printing 0           
}
```

Comment: This doesn't even compile (`public int value` versus `return Value`} ). Please dont do that. Give us a real [mcve], not something you copypastedslightlyedited.

Comment: And just for the record: always train to use proper names. Dont think "I learn programming first, and later, I apply good names". Nope, from the first second, try to use names that *mean* what they say, and say what they mean. Like: getter setters go along the variable name, so it would be getValue(), setValue() And: class names go UpperCase, always. And: you cant put all kinds of code of statements directly into the body of a class. Consider having a public static void main() in your **I**nit class, where you do these things.

Comment: In other words: please dont assume that this community is a "compiler error explanation service". Read a good book, follow it. When you dont understand java syntax, then dont try writing code. Read code. Type in code from a book. See what it does. And then, when you are a bit more proficient, then start writing your own code. But dont throw together code that has like 5 to 10 syntax errors and bring it to stackoverflow as question.

Comment: Edit: I edited public int value to public int Value. Its typo earlier.

Comment: I think @GhostCat is right... Nevertheless I can tell you that your code is printing 0 because obj1 is an object just initialized the line before, and the default value for a primitive int in a class is 0. I'm not sure you will understand this explanation as you may have to learn better Java programming before trying to actually code.

Comment: @Darnoj The above code doesnt compile. There is no point in speculating about runtime behavior for input that does **not** compile.

Comment: GhostCat, Darnoj I am recently staarted java programming. Above code I am able execute but not able to achieve what I wanted. If you have any idea please suggest. Thanks!

Comment: @Keshav Maybe it would be a good idea to start learning the theory in order to fully understand the base concepts before trying to do "real" code. It is not meant to be mean, I think you are doing the things in the wrong order. Even if someone provides a correct answer here won't imply that you truly understood the concepts. And to achieve this I would advice to read books, do online courses...

Comment: @Darnoj I agree with you. Unfortunately I was asked to do some real coding so early. So for a quick answers I came to this community.

Answer (score 0):

You are trying to read object 1 and 2 from `init` class but you have created object of `Class1` in `Class2` code.

There are complilation error in your code and also you have not followed proper naming conventions for Class and methods.

See below code where you need to define three separate class with public access modifier. All object initialization can be done in class constructor or you can define any public method

```
public class Class1{
  public int value;
  /*public void setMethod(int val){this.Value=val; -- here variable name is in small letter so compiler error}
  public int getMethod(){return Value;  -- here variable name is in small letter so compiler error}  -- getter setter name is not correct*/

 public void setValue(int val) {this.value=val;}
 public int getValue(){return this.value;}
}    

public class Init{
    Class1 obj1 = new Class1();
    Class1 obj2 = new Class1();

    public Init() {
        obj1.setValue(10);
        obj2.setValue(20);
        System.out.println("obj1 value is"+obj1.getValue()); // it will print 10
        System.out.println("obj2 value is"+obj2.getValue()); // it will print 20        
    }
}

public class Class2{
/*  Class1 obj1 = new Class1(); -- here obj1 will not refer to object in Init class
System.out.println("obj1 value is"+obj1.getMethod()); // it is printing 0           */
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Init init = new Init();
        Class1 obj1 = init.obj1;  
        System.out.println("obj1 value is"+obj1.getValue());// this will print 10       
    }
}
```

Comment: Hi there is a typo in my post, Class1 obj2 = new Class2(); in this line my objective is to create obj2 as a instance of Class1() not Class2().

Comment: corrected the typo mistake in my post too. Does my answer helps you?

Comment: I understood your point that obj1 will not refer to object in Init Class. And I tried your suggestion. But I am getting a compile error at line"Class1 obj1 = init.obj1" as "obj1 cannot be resolved or is not a field". I am still missing a basic thing here I think.

Comment: I have updated my post, here you need to define all three classes in separate file with .java extension. I forgot to put line of code which calls method in class under public constructor which is giving you an error. It should work for you now

Comment: Yes it is working now. Thank you very much Bhushan.

Answer (score 0):

Please make sure you first understand the difference between a class and an object (instance of a class).

For the rest of my answer, I assume that you have methods or constructors that contain the statements

Your code creates three objects:

- obj1 in init class, an instance of class Class1
- obj2 also in init class, an instance of class Class2
- obj1 in Class2

The instance in Class2 is never initialized. Thus, value is 0.

If you need to pass an instance of Class1 into Class2, you could do so in the constructor:

```
class Class1 {
...
}

class Class2 {
  // an instance of Class2 holds a reference to an instance of Class1
  private Class1 obj1;

  Class2(Class1 obj1) {
    this.obj1 = obj1;
  }
}

public class Main {
  public static final void main(String... args) {
    Class1 obj1 = new Class1();
    Class2 obj2 = new Class2(obj1);
  }
}
```

Comment: Hi there is a typo in my post, Class1 obj2 = new Class2(); in this line my objective is to create obj2 as a instance of Class1() not Class2().